# Form not POST ing

Tags: forms, yii2, html-post

this is my view where there is a form containig a field and a submit button.

```
<form id="typeheadForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Movie</label>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="state" id="movie_name" />
            </div>
        </div>

         <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Search' class="btn btn-squared btn-default">
    </form>
```

and below is my controller code

```
  public function actionMovies_all()
        {
            $this->layout = "main";
            if ( isset( $_POST[ 'movie_name' ] ) )
            {
             print_r("success");die();
            }
            if ( Yii::$app->request->post() )
            {
              print_r(Yii::$app->request->post());die();
            }
        }
```

i am not able to POST the form. what am i doing wrong?
i am getting an error " Bad Request (#400)
Unable to verify your data submission."

Comment: you didn't close your input (submit ) tag but I doubt that is the issue.  your also mixing ' single and " double quotes, which is just ugly.  And you don't have an action="?" in your form which might be an issue.

Comment: <form id="typeheadForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()
                                                                  ->createUrl( [ 'movies/movies_all',
                                                                               ] )?>"> i tried like this but it didnt work

Comment: Sorry I don't know Yii so I have no idea if that would work.  But you should look at the source of the page and make sure it goes where it should.  ( right click > view source ) then ctrl+f to find the word "form" and check that that is your url or what have you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `<form id="typeheadForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">` with

```
<?= \yii\helpers\Html::beginForm('', 'post', ['id' => 'typeheadForm', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']);?>
```

You are getting `bad request` because when you create your form manually, you did not include *csrf* token into it. When you create form with `Html::beginForm` method it takes care about it internaly.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function actionMovies_all()
    {
        $this->layout = 'main';
        if ( isset( $_POST[ 'submit' ] ) )
        {
         print_r('success');die();
        }
        if ( Yii::$app->request->post() )
        {
          print_r(Yii::$app->request->post());die();
        }
    }
```

Comment: or like this, if ( isset( $_POST[ 'state' ] ) )
        {
         print_r('success');die();
        }

Comment: i tried that to but same error Bad Request (#400)
Unable to verify your data submission.